# How safe is it to have references to union members in C++?

Tags: c++

Imagine this situation:

```
union Reg16
{
    uint16_t word;

    struct
    {
        uint8_t bottom;
        uint8_t top;
    };
};
```

Let's say I had something like this somewhere that uses this union:

```
Reg16 reg_AF;
uint8_t& reg_A = reg_AF.top;
uint8_t& reg_F = reg_AF.bottom;
```

Is it safe to keep a reference to the respective halves of the union even though the union does not technically always refer to a u8? I am not sure if this is a violation of strict aliasing rules, but it is worth noting that there is no reference anywhere to the `word`, only to `top` and `bottom`. Especially in this particular situation, the references are *supposed to* point to the top and and bottom halves of the entire u16, so there isn't any UB because I won't be getting any value I don't expect to get by reading them versus if I had a union of a float and an int and made a reference to each of those.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The code is not valid C++. There are no "unnamed struct" members in C++.

Comment: The reference is quite perfect. But: If you put waste inside the union and take the values from there you get trash out of it. As I understand your question you ask something about the live time of content of a variable. This is not related to the union anyway. It sounds that there is a deeper design flaw in your code.

Comment: @KerrekSB it is valid as a GCC/Clang extension, so that code compiles fine.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to say is that there is explicit language in the strict aliasing rule (section 3.10 of the C++03 standard)† which permits access to a value via `unsigned char`.  If `uint8_t` is a typedef for `unsigned char` then this usage will be unequivocally legal.

However, `uint8_t` can be typedef for an implementation defined type which is not `unsigned char` (although careful reading of the standard shows that if `uint8_t` exists, it must be the same size as `unsigned char`).  Further, this question can still be of interest for other types (eg `uint32_t` and `uint16_t`).

There is definitely no harm in the reference existing - the only danger could arise if the reference is *used* when the union contains `word` rather than `top` + `bottom`.  On the other hand, if that happens (and `top`/`bottom` are not `unsigned char`) then the strict aliasing rule has been violated.

Given that the C standard explicitly permits type punning via unions (unlike C++), there is a significant chance that your C++ compiler will allow it too.

Aside: strictly speaking the sample is not legal; anonymous structs are an extension supported by GCC, Clang, and MSVC (so the question is, which compilers *don't* support them).

† The wording has changed slightly in later versions, and the section number may have changed - but the principle stays the same.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your code is actually:

```
union Reg16
{
    uint16_t word;

    struct
    {
        uint8_t bottom;
        uint8_t top;
    } bytes;
};
```

This is perfectly fine *as a declaration*:

```
Reg16 reg_AF;
uint8_t& reg_A = reg_AF.bytes.top;
uint8_t& reg_F = reg_AF.bytes.bottom;
```

You can use the references exactly as you could use directly the struct members.

For example `reg_AF.bytes.bottom = 'A'; std::cout << ref_F;` is perfectly fine: the union currently contains the struct and you correctly use a reference to a struct member.

But this `reg_AF.word = 0x4142; std::cout << reg_A;` is UB(*) exactly as is `reg_AF.word = 0x4142; std::cout << reg_AF.bytes.bottom;`

---

(*) Per the strict aliasing rule you should not access a value from a different type that the one that was used to write it. As `struct bytes` is different from `uint_8`, the aliasing is incorrect. That being said, common compilers currently accept it *as an extension* for unions and even have options to ignore the strict aliasing rule. Simply the code is not standard conformant and another compiler could behave differently.